# 'spring.profiles.active=test' in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I want to set up `test` profile for all my spring component tests and place the `application.properties` with option `spring.profiles.active=test` into `src\test\resources` but this option is ignored. Why such behavior could happen?

I suppose that's could be because of property sources priorities but not sure https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

All works file with `@ActiveProfile` annotation but I don't want to place it at all tests (to much classes). Also, it works with `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` but the way with properties in the file is much more convenient.

Comment: use `spring.profiles.include=test` in `properties file

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunatelly also not working((

Comment: There are lot of tests with `@TestPropertySource` annotation. May be thay make some problems?

Comment: are you using `yml` or `properties` file ?

Comment: No. Simple `application.properties`

Comment: have you tried removing that `@TestPropertySource` annotation ?

Comment: No. And I can't do that quickly. A lot of tests with it.

Comment: you can place an application-test.yml (or application-test.properties) file under your test resource folder. You also need an application-default.properties file in test resource folder which contains ```spring.profiles.include=test```